# Modals in the past

Tags: semi-modals

My question is only about THE PAST.

Could (in the past)- we use it to state a fact or talk about an ability. He couldn't hear us. I couldn't swim when I was a kid.
Am I right? Do we also use could in different situations?

Could have (in the past)- is only for stating some probability. Something happened or not. She could have gone to work. It's possible that she's there but we're not certain. Is that right? Do we use could have in different situations in the past?

What I say here it only works like that with could right? I mean should is only used in the presence and future and should have is for the past thus only could  can be used in the past presence and future. Is the only modal which behaves like that? Is that right?

Comment: _Could have_ is not only for probability. _I could have gone to university if I had worked harder_. (Meaning - I was lazy and didn't get good enough exam results.)

Comment: Ok thank you and what about mu last questions ?

Comment: *You could have helped* and *You should have helped* are both past tense. The only difference is that interpreted *literally*, the first is about possibility / capability (what you *might* have done / were *able* to do), whereas the second is about recommendation / duty (what you *ought* to have done). But *in practice*, in conversational contexts, *You could have helped me!* is usually an even more bitter / emphatic complaint than *You could have helped me!*

Answer (score 0):

Yes - **should** refers to the **present** ("You should be able to see it through the telescope") or the future ("You should bring your sister next time you come").

**Should have** refers to the past. ("I should have brought my umbrella").